# List non-homeomorphic unions of three segments

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory

**Question:** Let $A$ be a collection of 3 closed line segments (of finite length) in the plane. Construct as many non-homeomorphic subspaces of the plane which are the union of these 3 line segments under the condition that when the lines intersect, the intersection is a singleton.

I've started drawing lots of circles and lines intersecting them and I'm worried I'm barking up the wrong tree. Could you help me understand what this question is asking and help me find some of the more difficult subspaces?

Edit: Changed 'union' 'intersection'.

Comment: As stated the question doesn't make sense.  First, line segments can't have a singleton as a union; do you mean the intersection?  Second, we don't have any control over anything here so there's just one union.  Did you mean to say we *pick* what A is?

Comment: Also, you're talking about circles here, which don't seem to have anything to do with the question.  Is part of the question missing?

Comment: Are you simply saying that $A$ is a union of 3 closed line segments in the plane and $A$ is connected?

Comment: Why were you concerned with any circles at all, when the question as stated is about line segments? Line segments are straight, circles are not.

Comment: My bad, I meant 'intersections' instead of 'unions'. I've changed it now.

Comment: I was drawing circles or triangles, remember that the lines can be curved or straight so triangle (3 line segments intersecting at their end points) can be drawn as a circle (3 curvy lines doing the same).

Answer (score 0):

Any required subspace $X$ is an image of a plane embedding of the graph $G_X$ whose set of vertices is the set of endpoints and the intersection points of the segments of the collection. We can easily list all such graphs $G_X$ by the induction with respest to the number of $n$ segments. This gives the following lists of the possible required subspaces.

$n=1$:

I

$n=2$:

II, I, X, Y

$n=3$:

[image]

It is easy to check (mainly by looking of sets of connected components created after removing crossroad points) that all listed subspaces are mutually non-homeomorphic.

Comment: "When the lines intersect, the intersection is a singleton."

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes. The subspaces above satisfy this condition. They are drawn up to a homeomorphism, so the segments which constitute a subspace are not necessarily straight-line.

Comment: OK. I misinterpreted the first diagram under $n=3$ as three identical segments, one on top of the other, but now I recognize that it's actually three segments laid end to end.